# React native & redux : facebook login error

Tags: facebook, react-native, redux

I try to create a facebook login using react native sdk and redux, 
I work a lot on the code but I still have this error when I refresh my app :

```
Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
```

I don't understand why, because I all my files are correctly imported in each files ..

the reducer :

```
import { LOADING, ERROR, LOGIN, LOGOUT } from '../actions/types';

function loginReducer(state = {loading: false, loggedIn: false, error: null}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOADING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: true
      });
    case LOGIN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        loggedIn: true,
        error: null,
      });
    case LOGOUT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        loggedin: false,
        error: null
      });
    case ERROR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: false,
        loggedin: false,
        error: action.err
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default loginReducer;
```

the index file for reducer :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loginReducer from './authReducer';
import profileReducer from './profileReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: loginReducer
});
```

the action :

```
import {
  LOADING,
  ERROR,
  LOGIN,
  LOGOUT,
  ADD_USER
} from './types';
import { facebookLogin, facebookLogout } from '../src/facebook';

export function attempt() {
  return {
    type: LOADING
  };
}

export function error(err) {
  return {
    type: ERROR,
    err
  };
}

export function loggedin() {
  return {
    type: LOGIN
  };
}

export function loggedout() {
  return {
    type: LOGOUT
  };
}

export function addUser(id, name, profileURL, profileWidth, profileHeight) {
  return {
    type: ADD_USER,
    id,
    name,
    profileURL,
    profileWidth,
    profileHeight
  };
}

export function login() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(attempt());
    facebookLogin().then((result) => {
      dispatch(loggedin());
      dispatch(addUser(result.id, result.name, result.picture.data.url, result.picture.data.width, result.data.height));
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch(error(err));
    });
  };
}

export function logout() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(attempt());
    facebookLogout().then(() => {
      dispatch(loggedout());
    })
  }
}
```

the facebook API :

```
import {
  LoginManager,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

const facebookParams = 'id,name,email,picture.width(100).height(100)';

export function getInfo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const profileInfoCallback = (error, profileInfo) => {
      if (error) reject(error);

      resolve(profileInfo);
    };

    const profileInfoRequest =
      new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        {
          parameters: {
            fields: {
              string: facebookParams,
            },
          },
        },
        profileInfoCallback
      );

    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(profileInfoRequest).start();
  });
}

export function facebookLogin() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'], (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        reject('error: ' + error);
      } else {
        if(result.isCancelled) {
          reject('error: login cancelled');
        } else {
          getInfo().then((userDetails) => {
            resolve(userDetails);
          }).catch((requestError) => {
            reject(requestError);
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

export function facebookLogout() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    LoginManager.logOut();
    return resolve();
  });
}
```

and the Login containers :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, text, ActivityIndicatorIOS } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions';
import LoginButton from '../../components/Login';
import reducers from '../../reducers';
import { Card, CardSection, Button } from '../../components/common';


class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const { actions, auth } = this.props;
    let loginComponent = <Login onLoginPressed={() => actions.login()} />;
    if(auth.error) {
      loginComponent = <View><Login onLoginPressed={() => actions.login()} /><Text >{auth.error}</Text></View>;
    }
    if (auth.loading) {
      loginComponent = <ActivityIndicatorIOS size="large" color="#3b5998" />;
    }
    return(
      <View>
        { auth.loggedIn ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : loginComponent }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Doest someone have any idea where the error is ?

Thank you !

**EDIT**

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import loginReducer from './authReducer';
import profileReducer from './profileReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: loginReducer
});
```

The error screen :
[image]

Comment: Can you please post the code for the file which shows your root reducer/combineReducers for your redux store?

Comment: Can you also post the full error log that you see when the error occurs? It may help in debugging the error. My hunch is that it is coming from this.props.auth not being defined for some reason. Can you console log `this.props.auth` in the line right after your `render() { ` and post what it returns?

Comment: @YoWakita I have this : Object {loading: false, loggedIn: false, error: null} and I post in my question the screen of the error

Comment: @YoWakita actually, I have `Object {loading: false, loggedIn: false, error: null}` AND `undefined` under this ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137982/discussion-between-yo-wakita-and-antonin-mrchd).